# $compile not updating dynamically generated html runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive-link

Here is jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/vikramkute/eq3zpmp9/5/

I am new to angular. I have an object which needs to be appended runtime in html. I am using angular 1.2.25

Expected output is

```
1 Quest
2 Quest
3 Quest
```

but I am getting last value repeated three times. As per my trial and error, I feel problem is with $compile. I tried different solutions provided on different forums but nothing worked. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

In Directive (within link function)

```
            scope.obj =
            [
                {
                    "questionText": "1 Quest"
                },
                {
                    "questionText": "2 Quest"
                },
                {
                    "questionText": "3 Quest"
                }
            ]

            scope.addData = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.obj.length; i++) {
                    addSlide(scope.obj[i]);
                }
            }

           addSlide = function (obj) {
               scope.singleObj = obj;
               el = $('<div ng-bind="singleObj.questionText"></div>');
               scope.owl.append(el);
               $compile(el)(scope);
           };
```

Output:

```
3 Quest
3 Quest
3 Quest
```

Here is full directive:

```
angular.module('journeycarousel', [])
    .directive('journeyCarousel', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '../components/journeyCarousel/journeyCarousel.html',
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, element) {

                scope.obj =
                    [
                        {
                            "questionText": "1 Quest"
                        },
                        {
                            "questionText": "2 Quest"
                        },
                        {
                            "questionText": "3 Quest"
                        }
                    ]

                scope.addData = function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.obj.length; i++) {
                        addSlide(scope.obj[i]);
                    }
                }

                addSlide = function (obj) {
                    scope.singleObj = obj;
                    el = $('<div ng-bind="singleObj.questionText"></div>');
                    scope.owl.append(el);
                    $compile(el)(scope);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Above code is simplified version. This is actual code:

```
    scope.singleObj = obj;
    el = $('<div class="questionContainer" <div ng-repeat="obj in singleObj"> ng-click="onSlideClick($event,singleObj)"> <div class="item"> <div class="questionSection" ng-bind="singleObj.questionText"></div> <div class="answerSection" ng-bind="singleObj.questionAnswer + singleObj.questionUnitOfMeasure"></div> </div> </div>');
   $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('add', el).owlCarousel('update');
   $compile(el)(scope);
```

Comment: Show your full code for directive.

Comment: use `terminal: true` in your directive

Comment: pro.mean I tried terminal: true. but no luck. If I add $('.owl-carousel').append(scope.singleObj.questionText); then I am getting 3 different value. but somehow $compile is taking last one. I tried to debug and found that first call come with first value. second call comes with second value but updates both first and second place and third call will update all 3 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason your output is

```
3 Quest
3 Quest
3 Quest
```

because digest cycle kicks in only after for loop is executed for 3 times in your case.
So, by the end of the 3rd iteration

```
scope.singleObj
```

will always be

```
{
     "questionText": "3 Quest"
}
```

So, all of the complied elements will always refer to same `scope.singleObj`

to get rid of that you can do

```
$scope.singleObj = [];
var addSlide = function(obj, i) {
    $scope.singleObj.push(obj);
    var ele = '<div ng-bind=\"singleObj[' + i + '].questionText"></div>'
    el = $(ele);
    $("#container").append(el);
    $compile(el)($scope);
};

$scope.addData = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.newCarouselSlideData.length; i++) {
        addSlide($scope.newCarouselSlideData[i], i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Below structure, probably you are messing up with object oriented concept:

```
addSlide = function (obj) {
        scope.singleObj = angular.copy(obj);
        el = $('<div ng-bind="singleObj.questionText"></div>');
        scope.owl.append(el);
        $compile(el)(scope);
};
```

Comment: This is also not working. Anyways thanks for you help.

Comment: can you make the fiddle, so that I can check directly over there?

Comment: Yes will do. give me some time. Thanks.

Comment: Use updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eq3zpmp9/6/
Multi addition won't working as ng-repeat will throw exception for duplicates.

Comment: fiddle I have created is simplified version of what I am doing. adding all items in an array and using ng-repeat won't help. I have to add one item at a time. Any other way with minimal updates?

Comment: Why do you thing ng-repeat won't help? If its not working you can go with workaround

Comment: Because instead of append I have to use "$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('add', el).owlCarousel('update');" this is for updating owl carousel runtime. I can pass only one item in it at a time. If I use ng-repeat all 3 items will go in one slide.

Comment: Check with another workaround if not then add support for  "$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('add', el).owlCarousel('update');" to accept it as list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124265/discussion-between-techfreak-and-pravin-erande).